# laptop shows no reaction to power button

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, power

I wanted to install Linux on an old Lenovo G585.

I interrupted a Xubuntu install process rudely while it was copying data (after the keyboard layout and language configuration).

Now the laptop doesn't even show a light or make any sound when I hit the power button (short or long, neither with batter nor on power supply). This error seems very basic, in particular I suppose it must be a hardware error. The only reasons I can think of are

- The power button is broken.
- Something regarding the internal power distribution/voltage regulation is broken.
- Some other very basic hardware error has occurred (a short circuit, the CPU became dislodged).
- A discharge of static electricity damaged the CPU or some other basic circuit.
- A friend says that a depleted small CMOS mainboard battery may brick a computer, but I think he's wrong (the BIOS will simply lose all user settings and start every time with the defaults, which is at worst annoying).

This is a very basic question but I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything. I did go to the google before writing this question but many of the hits seemed unreliable or questionable or were answering boot issues (as opposed to a completely dead machine).

Bottom line:

Is my thinking correct that unless there is a basic hardware problem I should always see *some*thing when I press the power button (typically the BIOS/UEFI)? And a Linux installation does not overwrite the BIOS (which, interrupted, could probably brick any PC)?

Comment: You should always get some indication of it trying to reach POST, fans, a light somewhere. To reach BIOS it has to get one more step past that, so isn't guaranteed. If the computer has a CMOS battery, it's about $£€ 0.80 to change it. Probably worth the effort.

Comment: "I interrupted a Xubuntu install process rudely." Be more specific how you did that... holding the power button for ~10 seconds (no big deal, should not have caused issue), pulling out he battery (or power cord if battery dead) while the PC was running...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Power button

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, likely that did no harm -- and even if it had it would only have been to the HDD, and you should be able to get to BIOS. Certainly, replacing the CMOS cell is an inexpensive thing to test. Check for loose connections -- perhaps a wire came off the power switch, or the lid switch has become stuck, as if the case were closed.